# symfony proprety accessor on arrayCollection elements

Tags: php, symfony

how can I access elements from arrayCollection of an Object?
exp:

```
Class Addresses
{
    private $country;
    private $code;

    public function getCountry()
    {
        //...
    }

    public function getCode()
    {
        //...
    }
}

Class Person{


    public function getAddresses()
    {
        // return ArrayCollection $addresses;
    }
}
```

now to access person addresses if it exist I have to do:

```
$addressArray = $accessor->getValue($person, 'Addesses');
foreach ($addressArray as $address){
    $outputArray['country'][] = $accessor->getValue($address, 'country');
}
```

But it seems that accessor doesn't accept arrayCollection. Is it true? else what's the error that I have made?

Comment: Why are you not just doing `$addressArray = $person->getAddress();`? You also seem to have a lot of problems with your codes... Why does `getAddresses()` accept args?

Comment: @iroegbu thx,yes you are right get() shouldn't accept args it's just an example it's not really my code.I just want to show the accessor limitation handling with arrayCollection. the problem that I do a foreach on my object so I don't really know weither the element is an attribute or an arrayCollection.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you can check if the returned type is an instance of `ArrayCollection` before attempting to loop over it.

```
$address = $person->getAddress();
if ($address instanceof ArrayCollection) {
    foreach($address as $key => $value) {
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

If you can do without the accessor, I don't see what advantage it adds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your property path: `addresses` instead of `person.Addesses` and `country` instead of `address.country`.

#### Update:

I'm pretty sure `PropertyAccessor` can return an `ArrayCollection` or what ever you want return from your data model. The accessor does not make any decision which will return and which will not. But I can't help you figure it out because the example codes abow lack of informations and has errors it-self.

As the answer abow, the problem in your property path still exist. It should be `addresses` instead of `Addesses` and your `Person` class should be:

```
class Addresses
{
    private $country;

    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }
}

class Person
{
    /**
     * @var Collection|Addresses[]
     */
    private $addresses;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getAddresses()
    {
        return $this->addresses;
    }
}

// Example usage
$person = new Person();
$accessor = new PropertyAccessor();
$addresses = $accessor->getValue($person, 'addresses');

if (!($addresses instanceof Collection)) {
    die('Impossible');
}
```

After update your code as my example abow. If you still has any error, please show the error message, detailed code in your model and how you call them.. that I can help.

Comment: you are right but the problem that I 'm trying to show here is that the accessor doesn't return ArrayCollection Elements. there is problem with handling the collection proprieties.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the property accessor supports collection reading and writing.
This can be achieved by the following.

```
$accessor = new PropertyAccessor();
$accessor->getValue($person, 'addresses[0].country');
```